# Bold and colored figure caption label in beamer?

Tags: beamer, floats, captions, beamerposter

I'm working on a beamer poster and would like my figure labels to be both bold font and colored. I'm using the command `\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=period, labelfont=bf}` to configure the caption, which gives me the bold font, but sets the color back to black. Anyone know how to get both?

### Edit

I was able to get the desired effect by placing the following lines in the header:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mycaption}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}#1 #2. }
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=mycaption, labelsep=none, labelfont=bf}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use the `caption` package for this; use

```
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[period]
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}

\setbeamerfont{caption name}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[period]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use the `caption` package for this (make sure your `caption` package is updated):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mycaption}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}#1#2}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=mycaption, labelsep=period, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm also being asked to change the colon to a period, for formatting reasons. Is there a way to do that without the caption package? It seems like using caption interferes with the settings from beamer.

Comment: Oh wait... that command is also making the caption itself bold. That's not what I need. I just want the part that says "Figure. 1" to be bold.

Comment: @MRule My bad. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @MRule I also took care of using a period as caption separator.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, I really appreciate your help. For some reason, it isn't working. It's probably interacting with other customizations that I'm using. I'll prepare a minimal example to reproduce the effect later -- have to go to a meeting now but will be back in a few hours.

Comment: @MRule No problem. In the meantime I added another option using the `caption` package.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thanks! That got me on the right track. I ended up using a slightly different customization, which I will place in the original question.